# Unable to Load Some Layers in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I have configured a QGIS Project file in QGIS 3.22 and used the QFieldSync version 3.4.4 to create a QField Package Project File to be imported into my tablet. However, I encountered this error upon loading the QGS file in QField.

Some of my colleagues also encountered this error. As a workaround, they closed their QGIS project and then repackaged again the project using QFieldSync. They transferred the file to their tablets and luckily the error was fixed and the following layers were able to be loaded.

I did the same workaround but still encountered this error.

What could be the cause of this error?

[image]

Comment: Similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/451053/211352

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I turned my .shp files into GeoPackages and everything loaded fine.

(If you did what I did and spent hours working on styles and labels, you can copy and paste the entire formatting in one go by right clicking on the existing layer and choosing Styles>Copy Style>All Style Categories and then clicking the new GeoPackage file and and Styles>Paste Style>All Style Categories - it saved me HOURS!)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on several versions of QFieldSync and QGis, some random layers simply refused to load on the Qfield app.
To me, it happened both using shape and geopackage layers.
The solution I found was to use as a different path for the project output from the QFieldSync plugin. I would consider using a shorter and without spaces path.
I'm currently using QGis3.22 and its QFieldSync plugin version 4.4.9

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this error and for me, it was a problem with the paths. Before you "Package for Qfield", you need to "Configure Current Project". When the menu pops up, go to "General" and make sure you're using "relative" paths, not "absolute". I had to do this because my phone wouldn't let me write to it (some security thing I presume). Instead, I wrote to my hard drive. After that, I connected my phone to the computer, then manually moved the files to my phone. If you didn't set the path to "relative", then the package file would be using absolute paths, which pointed to my hard drive, which obviously don't exist on my phone, hence the need to use relative paths. This fixed the error for me.

With respect to your problem, I see it's using relative paths (i.e. the leading "../" in your path). Make sure those files are found in the correct relative path or else it won't work. That's my advice...not sure it fixes your problem, but I thought I would share my experience.

(Using QGIS 3.22, QFieldSync 4.6, and QField 2.8.7)