# Unable to Upload Layer to QField App via QField Cloud

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

So I am trying sync my QGIS project with the QField app by using Qfield Cloud. I am able to successfully sync two point layers but the background imagery fails to import properly. The error message I get specifically says:

[image]

I produced the background imagery using the Generate XYZ tiles (MBTTiles) tool. I am also running the QField app on an ios device. When I go to QField.Cloud and check the logs I don't seem to be able to find any information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that the packaging error was from not having the file saved in the same folder as the QGIS project cloud file. The file was previously saved in the same folder as the original project file.